# RavenDb - Recursive queries/indexes, for Hierarchical Document

Tags: c#, ravendb

I know this might be a bit of a silly question, probably doing it 
wrong but I'll ask any way.

Lets say I have a set of Hierarchical Documents. 
The only information they contain about their place in the hierarchy 
is their parent id. If its null we have reached the top.

Getting parents and children are the easy part.

What I want to do is query for all the descendants and ancestors. 
I think I have to parts to this question.
1) To get the ancestors to a document is their any way to make a 
recursive query? Get the parent parent until parent is null.

2) Is their any way to make a index/projections where we can map the 
ancestor ids to a document. And then query the ancestor id or the 
document id? Because if I could get that index it would be easy to say 
get all documents by ancestor id for document id equal to the 
documentid i want to get the children from.

Lets say I have this structure.

Document 1
    Document 1.1
      Document 1.1.1
      Document 1.1.2
   Document 1.2
      Document 1.2.1

I want a index looking somthing like this

DocumentID
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.1.2
1.2
1.2.1
1.2.1

AncestorID
1
1
1.1
1
1.1
1
1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was discussed in detail on the RavenDB mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ravendb/ptBYL9A5PA8/discussion

The chosen solution, I believe, involved putting the full ancestry in each document.