# Recursive menu with Ravendb

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nosql, ravendb

I cannot seem to find a solid answer on this. I am a novice when it comes to Ravendb, so any help will be much appreciated. I am looking to build a recursive menu. What would be the best way to do this? I looked at this feed [RavenDb - Recursive queries/indexes, for Hierarchical Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471005/ravendb-recursive-queries-indexes-for-hierarchical-document), and was unable to find the 'recommended' solution. Do I just store all the child documents as denormalized data inside the parent document? I was thinking of storing the id of the document/page, and the document/page 'slug'. This seems viable since this is all the info I will need when building the menu, but what happens if the page title changes? I would then need to change the slug of the page, which means I would have to update the page parent. What happens if the page is deleted to? Do I just apply a patch? How does this method differ from using Live Projections? If anyone maybe has built a hierarchical-tree-app using Ravendb, that mimics 'best practices', I would be forever grateful.

Thanks

Tyrone

Comment: Tyrone, there's no single "correct" and "best" solution to do so. There are quite a few approaches like storing all the data in a single document (depending on the number of pages you'll have), using something similar to Raven's [Authorization Bundle](http://ravendb.net/bundles/authorization) to deal with hierarchies, etc. Could you further explain what you’re trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Carlos, I was just trying to build a hierarchal menu, and wondering what is considered to 'best' or right way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you implementing the Menu? You may want to take a look at this [Tree implementation](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/treet-implementing-a-non-binary-tree-in-c/) as a reference.

I would start by storing the whole Menu (your tree structure) data as a single document in RavenDB.

RavenDB's client is very good in terms of caching so even if you end up with a big document for the navigation that shouldn't be a problem as it will be always in memory.

Comment: Have you come across an example of this somewhere? Are you saying I should use a single document for all my pages with their fields, or just use a single document with normalized references to their original documents which include all fields?

Comment: Hi Tyrone, I was suggesting a single document to store the menu structure. Each menu node would have a reference to the page content as each page would be a document.